# Create function through MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql

How can I define a multi-statement function or procedure in using the MySQLdb lib in python?

Example:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(db='service')

c = db.cursor()

c.execute("""DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION trivial_func (radius float) 
    RETURNS FLOAT

    BEGIN
    IF radius > 1 THEN
        RETURN 0.0;
    ELSE
        RETURN 1.0;
    END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;""")
```

Which creates the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proof.py", line 21, in <module>
    DELIMITER ;""")
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 173, in execute
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //\nCREATE FUNCTION trivial_func (radius float) \n    RETURNS FLOAT\n\n   ' at line 1")
```

If I copy the same SQL directly into a mysql shell client, it works as expected

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `DELIMITER` command is a MySQL shell client builtin, and it's recognized only by that program (and MySQL Query Browser).  It's not necessary to use `DELIMITER` if you execute SQL statements directly through an API.

The purpose of `DELIMITER` is to help you avoid ambiguity about the termination of the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement, when the statement itself can contain semicolon characters.  This is important in the shell client, where by default a semicolon terminates an SQL statement.  You need to set the statement terminator to some other character in order to submit the body of a function (or trigger or procedure).

```
CREATE FUNCTION trivial_func (radius float) 
    RETURNS FLOAT

    BEGIN
    IF radius > 1 THEN
        RETURN 0.0; <-- does this semicolon terminate RETURN or CREATE FUNCTION?
    ELSE
        RETURN 1.0;
    END IF;
END
```

Since the API typically allows you to submit one SQL statement at a time, there's no ambiguity -- the interface knows that any semicolons inside the body of your function definition don't terminate the whole `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.  So there's no need to change the statement terminator with `DELIMITER`.

Comment: unless you need to. for example run a database creation script. is there any way to just pass raw SQL to MySql?

Comment: @BryanHunt, you can't submit an arbitrary SQL script through the dynamic SQL API, because several commands are recognized only by the `mysql` client, not the server SQL parser.

Comment: Answered in '09 and still kicking! Thank you!!

Answer (score 11):

To add to the answer by Bill Karwin, the following python code sample can be used to properly execute a string where DELIMITER is used, such as a database creation script.

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(db='service')
cursor = db.cursor()

dbString = """DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION trivial_func (radius float) 
RETURNS FLOAT

BEGIN
IF radius > 1 THEN
    RETURN 0.0;
ELSE
    RETURN 1.0;
END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;"""

# Find special delimiters
delimiters = re.compile('DELIMITER *(\S*)',re.I)
result = delimiters.split(dbString)

# Insert default delimiter and separate delimiters and sql
result.insert(0,';') 
delimiter = result[0::2]
section   = result[1::2]

# Split queries on delimiters and execute
for i in range(len(delimiter)):
    queries = section[i].split(delimiter[i])
    for query in queries:
        if not query.strip():
            continue
        cursor.execute(query)
```

This will execute one delimited statement at a time, changing delimiters when needed.

Comment: This did the trick for me.  I also needed to add `query = query.replace('%', '%%')`, to escape % characters in my .sql file.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comment from @AaronS. This script will read in an SQL file, split it into discrete SQL commands and cope with whatever delimiters it finds.

```
    queries = []
    delimiter = ';'
    query = ''
    with open('import.sql', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.strip()
            if line.startswith('DELIMITER'):
                delimiter = line[10:]
            else:
                query += line+'\n'
                if line.endswith(delimiter):
                    # Get rid of the delimiter, remove any blank lines and add this query to our list
                    queries.append(query.strip().strip(delimiter))
                    query = ''

    for query in queries:
        if not query.strip():
            continue
        cursor.execute(query)
    cursor.close()
```