# Error in mysql syntax: Befor Update Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am setting up a master master replication and trying to do some tests by setting up a before update trigger.

I am getting an error when I run the code below

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_blogs
BEFORE UPDATE ON blogs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.updated_replication < OLD.updated_replication) THEN
  SET NEW= OLD ;
END IF;
END$$
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at
>   line 6

What I am trying to do is only allow the row to be updated if the new row has a greater `updated_replication(timestamp)` value.

I am using mysql.

Can any one please tell me where I am wrong. How can I debug such errors? Is this any kind of syntax error?

[image: Error that I get now]

Comment: Is line 6 `SET NEW= OLD ;`?

Comment: I am new to mysql. If its wrong then Is there any way so that I can quit without updating that row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

**First problem:** you can't `SET NEW = OLD`. You can only assign individual columns, not the whole row. So you could make sure the new value does not decrease:

```
IF (NEW.updated_replication < OLD.updated_replication) THEN
  SET NEW.updated_replication = OLD.updated_replication;
END IF;
```

But that will set one column and let any other columns change according to the UPDATE that spawned this trigger. That might leave you with data that doesn't agree with itself.

If you want the whole row to revert to the old column values, you'd have to write a series of assignments in the `SET` statement, one for each column of the row.

If you instead want to abort the whole update, then you need to learn the [SIGNAL feature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html).

```
IF (NEW.updated_replication < OLD.updated_replication) THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You can\'t travel backwards in time!';
END IF;
```

This doesn't roll back the transaction, just the single UPDATE that spawned the trigger. Any other changes made in the same transaction are still pending.

**Second problem:** you haven't set the `DELIMITER` when defining a trigger with a compound statement. See my answer here: [Create function through MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745538/create-function-through-mysqldb/745575#745575)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have gone through the SIGNAL docs but didnt understand what the '45000' denotes. Also will "SIGNAL " it affect other queries running in the same connection after the update?

Comment: The manual states: "To signal a generic SQLSTATE value, use '45000', which means 'unhandled user-defined exception.'"

Comment: As for affecting other queries, no, not any more than any other error (e.g. duplicate key violation) would. If you don't catch the signal with a signal handler, then the signal causes an error which makes the trigger fail, which makes the UPDATE that spawned it fail. If that UPDATE was itself invoked from a trigger, then that trigger fails and its spawned DML operation fails, all the way up to the client's request. But subsequent requests are not affected.

Comment: Thanks that worked. One more question, can I create the trigger for all tables in my database in a single stretch. I mean can I run a loop through the tables in the database and run the create trigger code? I tried it but I have no previous experience in such mysql coding.

Comment: There's no way to create a trigger for all tables. It would make little sense, because each table should have its own distinct set of columns, and referencing a non-existent column name in a given table would be an error. You can get a list of all tables from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. You can even get a list of tables that include a given column name by joining to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. But you might want to keep it simple -- just write an SQL script, copy & paste the trigger definition for each table.

Comment: Thanks, but the idea behind this is to create a field updated in all tables and check that field before all updated are made. ie when a master master replication is set up it will only allow the latest update to be executed.

Comment: Replication does not filter based on data values. But it does update only the rows that were updated on the master. And with master-master replication, it won't allow infinite loops. I think you may be trying to solve a problem that is already handled by default replication.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55921/discussion-between-user2742122-and-bill-karwin).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think assignment of a database record with `tableA = tableB` is legal which is essentially what `NEW=OLD` is doing.

It would be better to do some other operation if the update is not desired:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_blogs
BEFORE UPDATE ON blogs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.updated_replication >= OLD.updated_replication) THEN
  SET NEW.invalid = True;
END IF;
END;$$
```

Where `invalid` is a column added just for this purpose.  A periodically run stored procedure could then deal with such records, perhaps by deleting them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So ROLLBACK; will stop the current update and leave the record as it was right?

Comment: I have added an image in the post can you just check that and tell me why I am getting that error? I am just trying to learn some basics. I am using xampp in windows 7

The second set of code is also giving me the same error

Comment: @user2742122:  yep, check out the docs for [`rollback`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

Comment: You can't roll back inside a trigger: *ERROR 1422 (HY000): Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.*

Comment: @BillKarwin:  I am not surprised.  Therefore, use the flagging of a bad record alternative.

Comment: @all but SET NEW.invalid = True; is also giving the same error for me. Is it something else that I am missing?

Comment: @user2742122:  You'll have to add that column to the table.